# Connectors on wires entering a plastic box

Tags: electrical, connectors

I brought a 14/3 U/F cable into a single plastic nail-on box, through a hole that I drilled through the back of the box. Do I need a connector on that wire, and if so what would you recommend a black button Romex connector backwards?

Comment: What size hole did you drill?

Comment: I could easy fit a 3/4 or one inch black button romex connector on backwords but isk if thats cool

Comment: but why backwards?

Comment: By "connector" do you mean a strain relief clamp?

Comment: @isherwood For some reason the industry refers to cable clamps as "connectors". That would be like referring to your car's shocks as a "carburetor" but whatever.

Comment: I got snipped once by an inspector when I drilled a hole in the side several single gang plastic boxes because of unusual mounting requirements. I ran BX cable with the proper ends and everything.   He said I "modified" the box which isn't allowed. I think he was being overly picky, but he's the one with the badge.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that's accurate in a sense--you're connecting the cable shield to the junction box--also a shield in a sense.

Comment: OK.  I'll stop with this, bc it's getting to chitchat, but I've often wondered about the term "bonding" when it comes to connecting the grounding to the neutral. Why isn't it just "connected".   Oh well, maybe a real electrician knows the answer.

Comment: @D.M.Electricprotectyatech -- just tell us the size of the hole you put in the box and we'll go from there :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used listed clamps on construction boxes but black button connector is a device like an “insider” plastic clamp it is only listed for 1 direction. Mechanical 2 screw clamps can be installed with the screws on the inside or outside. On plastic boxes if you have a bushing to protect the insulation the staple needs to be within 8” not all plastic boxes have clamps but if you drill a hole it will require protection for the wire at a minimum. I would say based on that it doesn’t matter but if the instructions for your clamp provide a direction the inspector can flag it.